# Tibco & Windows Process Activation

Tags: messaging, tibco, wpas

I'm thinking about how I could scale out Tibco EMS queue listeners written in managed code (C# in this instance). I'm looking for predominantly isolation and clustering characteristics.

In MSMQ I could use Windows Process Activation Service to host and manage the number and lifetime of queue listeners.  Is there a Tibco equivalent?

Otherwise I suspect I'll end up with a simple NT service to host EMS listeners. (which in turn could perform process-activation).   Workable but fairly tricky to build a 24x7 monitorable, robust, production service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the TIBCO equivalent is [TIBCO ActiveMatrix Service Grid](http://www.tibco.com/products/soa/composite-applications/activematrix-service-grid/default.jsp). It supports C# service containers and can host and manage your C# listeners.

Couple this with [TIBCO ActiveMatrix Service Performance Manager](http://www.tibco.com/products/soa/governance/activematrix-spm/default.jsp) and you can have it automatically deploy and start more instances to more nodes during high load situations.

Comment: Yeah that seems just the ticket - this functionality new?  I moved on from Tibco in the end.

Comment: Active matrix is available for several years. other options include Tibco Business Works (an older product of Tibco) and using Message Driven Beans in a J2EE Application Server.

Comment: Dang. I didn't realise your question was so old, but yes, Service Grid is relatively new. From my vague recollection, it's only been around for 2 or 3 years.

Comment: Both the links are dead now